# Error 404 using RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, web, url-rewriting

I am currently improving the usability of a website through friendly URLs. I have done this several times and what I typically do is hide the *.php or *.html extension using .htaccess following this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

However, this code seems to resist to work in the server this website in hosted in.  I am getting a 404 not found error if I try to access without the extension added.

http://www.leddream.es/alquilar-pantalla-led.html

http://www.leddream.es/alquilar-pantalla-led

Any ideas of how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is the rewrite module enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am also adding the www. to the requests that come without it and works perfectly @Starkeen

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @anubhava. .htaccess file seems to work propertly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess just enable `MultiViews` option to enable extension-less URIs.

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.html`.

Do comment out all other rewrite rules after adding this line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Not working either. I tried that solution before aswell. Thanks for the suggestion @Starkeen